# How can I search without making the top item gone?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3

I want add Autocomplete for place, zip code, etc. like this:

[image]

Then I use Google Maps GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController for the data because if I use fetcher / GMSAutocompleteFilter the data is not complete like use that but every time I typing, the screen become:

[image]

The question is how can I search without make the top item gone? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google changing the size of UI elements, or the font used in table cells, is not supported.
You can achieve this by setting `resultsViewController` table cell background clear.

```
resultsViewController?.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

top item did not gone anywhere actually resultsViewController hide it. because resultsViewController cover whole view.

Comment: @EvanLaksana glad to help you.